# Is there difference in performance between not taking a return value and taking and discarding it?

Tags: c#

Given the initial code:

```
  callSomeFunction(someParameter);
```

Currently, the function returns but the value is not used. However, we need to provide a trace log, so we revise the code as thus:

```
#if DEBUG
    Debug.Print $"Entering function with {nameof(someParameter)}: {someParameter}";
#endif
   var result = callSomeFunction(someParameter);
#if DEBUG
   Debug.Print $"Leaving function with result: {result}";
#endif
```

In a release build, the code is basically equivalent to:

```
   var result = callSomeFunction(someParameter);
```

and obviously the `result` is not used. So with that changes, are there any performance ramifications just because it's now taking a return value when it originally wasn't? The original reasoning for not just making 2 different blocks was that doing the latter could be error prone since there's now 2 call sites to maintain whereas the version above keeps only 1 call site to maintain.

Comment: As an aside, the pre-processor directives are redundant here - `Debug.Print` already has a `Conditional("DEBUG")` [applied to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.print?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads), in release mode it won't get compiled anyway.

Comment: Well, at the very least the way the code is written, you have an allocation happening. So yes, there will be some memory used by the variable that will then need to be GC'd when control leaves the function. Additionally, the compiler may or may not inline your pure method, although i am not qualified to say that it definitely will make it faster if the method is pure.

Comment: Also, what you're doing with `#if` macros is really calling for AOP, so you might want to google around to find a framework that would take care of that for you

Comment: Excellent point RE: AOP - currently it's only one class that needs the functionality so handrolled solution seemed adequate. But you're definitely right - if this grows in scope, I definitely should consider using AOP instead. That said, I asked the question primarily for education.

Comment: RE: allocation - that's the part I am not 100% clear on - if a function returns something, the allocation still has to be made at the low level to take the return, no? You can't tell the function to put its result in a null pointer or something. So I'm wondering if an explicit variable simply just changes the address where the return is placed, rather than being a new allocation. Obviously that is pretty low-level beyond what we might see in C#.

Comment: Either the value or the reference returned ends up on the call stack after a function returns. The reference lives at the same address, whether you store this reference or not. See duplicate for more explanation.

Comment: Yes, the duplicate question was exactly what I was looking. Unfortunately my initial search failed to find that question. What is the procedure for handling a duplicate? Should I close this question?

Comment: @this no problem. Your question is now closed as duplicate of the other. There's nothing more you need to do. Your question will remain visible and point to the duplicate, so people who search the web use your wording will find this one, and find their answer in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference if you assign the return value to a variable or not.
At least with Release builds, the compiler will notice that you don't use `result` anywhere else and will optimize it away.

And even in Debug builds, at least no memory allocations (and thus no GC) will occur, because `result` will be assigned on the stack, since it's a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just analyse with my limited knowledge about .NET, due to the absence of context, there are two cases of `result`: [**value type** and **reference type**](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3043992/a-deep-dive-value-and-reference-types-in-net.html), but in both cases, the value of `result` already created in the `callSomeFunction`, the costs are only the **receiving** and **cleaning** part:

- `value type`: it's just some bytes on stack

  - the **receiving** just copied the whole value -- I don't know if the compiler gonna optimize to skip it
  - **cleaning** it need nothing, the stack gonna shrink as the current function call returned
- `reference type`: the memory already allocated in that `callSomeFunction` on **managed heap**

  - the **receiving** add a reference to it
  - **cleaning** it just remove the reference to the **value created in `callSomeFunction`**, at the end of current code block

So, from my viewpoint, it's not a big deal, I assume your program is not so critical on **performance** -- in that case, you would have chose some language more good at it.

Comment: It sounds like you believe .NET does reference counting - it doesn't. There's nothing to do with a reference type.